# How to match multiple languages

Tags: regex, go, unicode

I am writing a regex in golang to capture hashtags that might appear in different languages. For example obvious one is english, but there might be latin or arabic users who will try and create hashtags using those character set. 
I am aware of the unicode character class name but how can you use multiple at once without generating a regex for each one?

example code:

```
r, err := regexp.Compile(`\B(\#[[:ascii:]]+\b)[^?!;]*`)
```

This will match `"#hello #ذوق"` and output `[]string{#hello, #ذوق}` but not match for just `"#ذوق"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest using

```
\B#[\p{L}\p{N}\p{M}_]+
```

where `[\p{L}\p{N}\p{M}_]` is roughly the Unicode-aware `\w` pattern. The `\p{L}` matches any Uniciode letter, `\p{M}` matches any combining mark and `\p{N}` matches any Unicode digit.

See [Go demo](https://play.golang.org/p/pb0G8ILPsT1):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {
    text := "#hello #ذوق #citroën"
    r := regexp.MustCompile(`\B#[\p{L}\p{N}\p{M}_]+`)
    res := r.FindAllString(text, -1)
    for _, element := range res {
        fmt.Println(element)
    }
}
```

Output:

```
#hello
#ذوق
```

With `text := "#ذوق"`, [the output is](https://play.golang.org/p/Fl_Zop4CfZv) `#ذوق`.

See the [**regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/wWYBSb/2).

Comment: Your regex doesn't match #dérange, because the acute accent is a mark \p{M} not a letter. Change your regex to `\B#[\p{L}\p{N}_][\p{L}\p{N}\p{M}_]*`

Comment: @JGNI Probably, that level of conciseness is not necessary and `\B#[\p{L}\p{N}\p{M}_]+` will be enough. If there is a need to only match diacritics after letters, the pattern would look like `\B#(?:\p{L}\p{M}*|[\p{N}_])+`. If there was a requirement to only have a letter after `#`, it would look like `\B#\p{L}\p{M}*(?:\p{L}\p{M}*|[\p{N}_])*`. And so on and so forth.